# NoMethodError in Books#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning Ruby on Rails and I'm stuck with this problem. I've looked at the other similar problems but did not find a solution that worked for me.

Everything was working correctly but then I added a `f.file_field` to allow the user to select an image. Now if the user select an image I get this error but if he doesn't I don't get the error.

[image]

This is my model for Book

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category

  has_attached_file :book_img, styles: { book_index: "250x350>", book_show: "325x475>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :book_img, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

end
```

This is the part of the controller that I think is causing the error

```
  def new
    @book = current_user.books.build
    @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
  end

  def create
    @book = current_user.books.build(book_params)
    @book.category_id = params[:category_id]

    if @book.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

And this is the view

```
<%= simple_form_for @book, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select a category") %>
  <%= f.file_field :book_img %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Book Title" %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.input :author %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

I don't understand why I'm getting an error on the `select_tag` which allows the user to select the category of the book.

Ruby : ruby 2.2.6p396

Rails : Rails 5.0.2

Comment: restart the server and try again. also, do you have records in your `categories` table?

Comment: I restarted the server multiple times. And I added the categories manually and each book has a category_id

Comment: Is `book_img` in the `strong params`?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Yes it's in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `@categories` variable inside `create` action. Update it as below

```
def create
  @book = current_user.books.build(book_params)
  @book.category_id = params[:category_id]

  if @book.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

If `create` action fails it renders `new` template which tries to populate select tag with available categories inside `@categories` variable. And this variable was only set in `new` action.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That did fix the error but do you have any idea why it's not creating a new book?

Comment: Most likely because of validation on `book_img`. Try to inspect `@book.errors` after failed save. It should tell what is the problem.

Comment: Ya I'm getting an error with the paperclip gem I probably didn't install it correctly. Thank you for your help.